# What is the "unsupportedSupervisedAccount" youtube.common Authorization error?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I started getting the `unsupportedSupervisedAccount` reason on Aug 18th, 2021 but I don't see any matching description in [the YouTube API errors docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#youtube.api.CommonRequestError).

Can someone point me at the documentation for this error?

Example (sanitized) error:

```json
[
  {
    "message": "Access Forbidden. The authenticated user cannot access this service.",
    "domain": "youtube.common",
    "reason": "unsupportedSupervisedAccount",
    "location": "Authorization",
    "locationType": "header"
  }
]
```

Possibly related is this blog post: [*New safety and digital wellbeing options for younger people on YouTube and YouTube Kids*](https://blog.youtube/news-and-events/new-safety-and-digital-wellbeing-options-younger-people-youtube-and-youtube-kids/) but it has no technical details.

Comment: Did you consider what the message is saying the user you are authenticated with has been banned from YouTube pick a different user.

Comment: It doesn't say the user is banned.  I think it is saying supervised-accounts (i.e., kid accounts) are not supported/allowed (yet?) as part of their kid safety project.

Comment: IMO same thing that user cant use your system pick another user.  https://support.google.com/families/answer/9055704